# How to get the nth element of list using neural network?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, layer

I would like to add a neural network layer that takes as input from a output of another layer in the neural network and another separate number k and outputs the kth element of the list. This layer is supposed to be part a bigger deep network that supplies only the k element to succeeding layer.

The way i think is to dynamically change weights dynamically to a one hot array with only kth element  = 1 rest all zeros.

Second way would be to freeze weights and mutliply the previous layer out with the one hot output and input it to next layer. But I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can just compose top-k modules from [any library](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/top_k):

```
just_kth_element(x, k) := -topk(-topk(x, k=k), k=1)
```

Since kth element is nothing but **smallest element** in topK elements.

Or equivalent

```
just_kth_element(x, k) := min(topk(x, k=k))
```